# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'a')

Tags: javascript, class

I was trying classes and the this keyword in Javascript,and I wrote this code:

```
class p{
  constructor(p,a){
      p = p.p;
      a = p.a;
  };
};
const c = new p(p="1st aspect",a="2nd aspect");
console.log(this.c);
```

And I got this Error:

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'a')
```

I don't know whether this is compatible with classes or whether I passed in the wrong arguments,can someone help me there?

Comment: @evolutionxbox I wantet to try it out,I'm new at javascriipt....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax for creating a class is wrong. You don't need to pass the parameter names. Just use

```
const c = new p("1st aspect","2nd aspect");
```

And it is not good practice to use lowercased frist letter as class name. Use `P` instead of `p`. And `this.c` is wrong. Just print

```
console.log(c);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's just the syntax you're using to create a class instance isn't correct in terms of attempting to use provided argument names ("p =", "a ="), and there may be some errors in your class construction. I think you may have been trying to do something like this:

```js
class p {
  // These are ordered arguments, not named arguments 
  constructor(p,a) {
      // Save the value of p and a on the class instance
      this.p = p;
      this.a = a;
  };
};
// Create a new p class instance with the arguments in order
const classInstance = new p("1st aspect", "2nd aspect");
```

Answer (score 0):

Code should look like this

```js
class P {
  constructor(p, a){
      this.p = p;
      this.a = a;
  };
};


const c = new P("1st aspect", "2nd aspect");
console.log(c); // <- just print c
```

I can see you're mixing some concepts and getting confused, I'd suggest you to read [official MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes), you'll learn about classes step by step.

As an extra, you'll notice that class names are named using [PascalCase](https://techterms.com/definition/pascalcase). This is because by following the naming convention you'll read and understand other people's code much faster (and even yours).

Hope this helped!